# Can't find html table on source code of a website

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I'm a member in a website and there's a huge (automatically generated) HTML table on this PHP page that is only available to me and I wanted the table source code because I want to copy it to a HTML page on my computer to then process it with a program.

The problem is that when I right-click to display the page source code it works. However, I'm tired of looking at the source code and inside all the linked JavaScript files. I can't seem to find the table or any data of it on the scripts/page source codes.

I can select the table data and copy it, but it is just the data. It doesn't say anything about flash, so I'm assuming it's not flash. The data of the scripts/pages isn't obfuscated, it's easily human-readable.

I used Google Chrome's 'inspect element' and it worked.

I was thinking on doing a PHP script that would import data from a similar table, but I will have to know more about a lot of stuff mentioned here.

What can I be doing wrong or what can cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Can you visit the page in Chrome? When you right-click there'll be an "Inspect Element" option.

Comment: No link or source code?! It's gonna be pretty hard for anyone to give a direct answer

Comment: @OscarGodson He said "*page that is only available to me*" making a public link useless and his entire problem is he can't find the source code. Also, I voted this be moved to webmasters b/c his goal appears to copy/paste content rather than a specific programming problem.

Comment: @Mike B being a webmaster doesn't actually mean that you will know for sure what kind of code can cause this effect, i ask stuff on the webmasters part when i think it's a webmasters question, i wanted to know what could i be doing wrong (not programming) or what could cause this behaviour (programming). thank you for clarifying the 'link thing to OscarGodson'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible reasons could be that the table may be returned from an AJAX call to another page that returns the HTML for the table, or they could be generating the table's html code and contents on the fly from a list of values coming from javascript or some other source rather than serving the HTML output to you from the server side.

Something you can do to figure it out is see if there are any empty div or other html elements where the table appears to be inserted, and search their javascript files for references to those elements.  That may shed some light on how they populate it.

Feel free to update your question with the raw html (where you don't see the table) and maybe some javascript and we can look.  Use pastebin if it is a lot of content.

Comment: it's a pretty long page but eventually i found some empty elements for a lot of stuff, confirmed with google chrome's inspect element option that one of it was for the table and i could expand all the data from it and copy it. you don't mention directly the google chrome option that solved my problem but your answer is the more comprehensive regarding the problem at hand that was "identifying the table directly from the source code and copying the table content (html included)" not "copying directly the table from the browser with html included"

Answer (score 2):

Would it help to use the Firefox plugin called Firebug?

Using this plugin you can click on an area of a page to see the code displayed in the Firebug section at the bottom of your window.

Here are the details: https://getfirebug.com/whatisfirebug

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the table is generated with a JS script, if that's the case, doing right click and "View source" would not show you the html. You need to use something like Chrome's devtools. Open google chrome and visit that page, once there, right click the table and select "Inspect element", the devtools will open and then you'll see the table's code, right click it's opening tag and select "Copy as html".

Let me know if that works :)

Comment: that worked pretty well for copying the table with html included, directly

Answer (score 0):

Try a developer extension like http://getfirebug.com/ The underlying source code may not reflect output due to how much the DOM can be modified by javascript with extensive use of ajax. This plugin will permit you to view elements as they're interacting with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

its probably that the table is dynamically generated on the fly so looking at the source code won't actually give you much. try looking at the "GENERATED" source code or inspecting the DOM using Firebug, or the Developer tools of chrome/safari.

Or better yet, try your hand at web scraping:

http://vancouverdata.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-web-scraping-xpath-html-google.html

Although I'm not sure if it'll work for pages that need a login. But hey, at least you learned something new :p